# Dynamically Created Columns from Selected Columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My current dataset is in the following format.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'a' = np.random.randn(6),
'b' = np.random.randn(6),
'c' = np.random.randn(6),
'd' = np.random.randn(6),
'e' = np.random.randn(6),
'f' = np.random.randn(6)
})
```

My updated dataset looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'a' = np.random.randn(6),
'b' = np.random.randn(6),
'c' = np.random.randn(6),
'd' = np.random.randn(6),
'e' = np.random.randn(6),
'f' = np.random.randn(6),
'alpha' = np.random.randn(6),
'beta' = np.random.randn(6),
'gamma' = np.random.randn(6)
    })


where alpha = df['a']*2
beta = df['b']*5
gamma = df['c']*6
```

Both the final 3 columns (`alpha, beta & gamma`) & input columns (`a,b,c`) and numeric values (`2,5,6`) are variables so getting pass from outside as list.

So, I was trying this following code:

```
newCol = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma']
oldCol = ['a', 'b', 'c']
numVal = [2, 5, 6]

for i in range(len(newCol)):
     
      df[newCol[i]] = df[oldCol[i]]*numVal[i]
```

But I'm getting the following error:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'`

Can someone please tell me how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: `pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(6),...` is the correct way to write it

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: @gtomer: The updated dataset will have `alpha`, `beta` & `gamma`. I created the dummy dataset, so that the format of the data can be clear. The values of these columns given by the calculation (multiplication of original column with some number). The loop is throwing the error. There must be some dynamic way to create new column.

Comment: @Beta Actually your solution works without an error. I just tried it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `zip` function and a simple `for` loop:

```
In [24]: for i,j,k in list(zip(numVal, oldCol, newCol)):
    ...:     df[k] = df[j] * i
    ...: 

In [25]: df
Out[25]: 
          a         b         c         d         e         f     alpha      beta      gamma
0  0.737824  1.085417  1.369061  0.565950 -2.075468 -0.929977  1.475647  5.427085   8.214369
1 -1.337789  0.278580 -1.880562  0.082981 -0.487926  0.553878 -2.675578  1.392898 -11.283371
2 -0.711687 -0.698380  2.051574 -0.846402 -0.580580  0.031335 -1.423375 -3.491900  12.309442
3  0.239819 -1.092086  0.734303 -3.621612 -0.111699  1.675823  0.479638 -5.460428   4.405819
4 -0.320136 -0.406935  0.680605 -0.711390  0.176590  0.177886 -0.640271 -2.034674   4.083632
5 -0.174353 -0.750984 -0.057860  1.696935 -0.210906  2.786231 -0.348707 -3.754922  -0.347160
```

Comment: Great. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, then you can use this:

```
df[newCol] = df[oldCol].mul(numVal, axis=1)
df
```

Output:

```
          a         b         c         d         e         f     alpha       beta     gamma
0 -0.725042 -0.756909  0.070109  0.850219  1.792450  1.324259 -1.450084  -3.784547  0.420656
1 -0.062379 -0.105332 -1.222571 -1.297675 -0.514850  0.610115 -0.124758  -0.526659 -7.335425
2  1.396269 -0.602535  0.033669  1.190688  0.335367  1.287264  2.792537  -3.012675  0.202014
3  0.303298 -2.016903  0.748448  0.317952 -0.319775 -1.023614  0.606595 -10.084517  4.490689
4 -0.469161 -2.133385 -0.488404  1.322836  0.560578  1.436018 -0.938321 -10.666927 -2.930423
5 -0.177657 -1.065320 -0.103551  0.406531  0.128109  0.387128 -0.355314  -5.326601 -0.621305
```

Comment: This answer is sleek. But Mayank's is more readable. But thanks for your asnwer.

Comment: @Beta Happy coding and be safe and stay healthy.